# How do I add multiple button that go to different scenes please?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

Can someone please tell me the code to have multiple buttons that go to different scenes, I am using Xcode 6 Swift.

This is the code I have at the moment and it works perfect but I want to make the button image 'score' go to another scene, can someone please tell me how.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let playbutton = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "play")
    let score = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "score")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.playbutton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(self.playbutton)
        self.backgroundColor  = UIColor(hex: 0x80D9FF)

        self.score.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 100)
        self.addChild(self.score)
        self.backgroundColor  = UIColor(hex: 0x80D9FF)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.playbutton {
                var scene = PlayScene(size: self.size)
                let skView = self.view as SKView
                skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
                scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
                scene.size = skView.bounds.size
                skView.presentScene(scene)
            }
        }
    }
}

func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
```

Comment: that is the main scene where the game is

Comment: Then just do the same thing as the code chunk below `if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.playbutton`, but use `self.score` and your other scene that you initialize. I don't understand your problem.

Comment: I've tried that but I get the error : "Use of unresolved identifier 'self' "on both lines where self.size and self.view is

Comment: What's the name of your other scene? Your first is called `PlayScene`. What's the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.playbutton {
            var scene = PlayScene(size: self.size)
            scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
            scene.size = skView.bounds.size
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        } else if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.score {
            var scene = HighScore(size: self.size)
            scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
            scene.size = skView.bounds.size
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously if the only difference is the scene itself, start with the if/else by only setting the scene var (define it before the if/else), and then apply all the parameters after the if/else. Saves you duplicating code. And if you have many more of those scenes, consider a switch statement.